# In Visual Studio 2013 I simply want to pass data to a sql table using VB?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am designing an application which is my forte but now have to code the back end. I am using Visual Studio 2013 with DevExpress and SQL Server 2014. It may be a simple question but I have struggled to find a straight answer anywhere. I have an asp.net book but I still cant find an answer. I think I have connected my whole solution with a connection string in that I can populate the tables and stored procedures into my dataclass. I simply want to add any user input into a table on SQL Server using a button with an onclick event. Surely it cant be that difficult but remember I am a bit of newbie so any help would be greatly appreciated. If there is any questions you need answered to assist then let me know. I am writing in VB script but am struggling to get it to work. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
     Protected Sub btnAddNewSource_Click(sender As System.Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNewSource.Click


    'ErrDetails.Text = ""
    'ErrDetails.Visible = False
    'FocusSet = False
    'errCount = 0
    'ErrDetails.Text = ""

    'If txtSourceFunding.Text = "" Then
    '    ErrDetails.Text = ErrDetails.Text + "Did you enter the funding source?" + vbNewLine
    '    ErrDetails.Visible = True
    '    txtSourceFunding.Focus()
    '    FocusSet = True
    '    errCount = errCount + 1
    'End If

    'If txtContributionFunding.Text = "" Then
    '    ErrDetails.Text = ErrDetails.Text + "Did you enter the contribution?" + vbNewLine
    '    ErrDetails.Visible = True
    '    txtContributionFunding.Focus()
    '    FocusSet = True
    '    errCount = errCount + 1
    'End If

    'If cmbStatus.Value = -1 Then
    '    ErrDetails.Text = ErrDetails.Text + "Did you inform us of the status?" + vbNewLine
    '    ErrDetails.Visible = True
    '    cmbStatus.Focus()
    '    FocusSet = True
    '    errCount = errCount + 1
    'End If

    'If FocusSet = True Then
    '    ErrDetails.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
    '    ErrDetails.Height = 20 * errCount
    '    ErrDetails.Visible = True
    '    Return
    'End If

    'Dim btnSource = (From o In dc1.Update_GrantApplicationCycleFunding Where o.GrantApplicationID = Session("CurrentProjectID").ToString).FirstOrDefault
    'If Not IsNothing(btnSource) Then
    '    btnSource.GrantApplicationID = Session("CurrentProjectID")
    '    btnSource.GrantApplicationCycleFundingSource = txtSourceFunding.ToString
    '    btnSource.GrantApplicationCycleFundingContribution = txtContributionFunding.ToString
    '    btnSource.GrantApplicationCycleFundingStatusID = cmbStatus.ToString
    '    btnSource.GrantApplicationCycleFundingNotes = memFundingNotes.ToString

    'Else

    '    Dim NewGrantApplicationCycleFundings As New GrantApplicationCycleFunding
    '    With NewGrantApplicationCycleFundings
    '        .GrantApplicationID = Session("CurrentProjectID")
    '        .GrantApplicationCycleFundingSource = txtSourceFunding.ToString
    '        .GrantApplicationCycleFundingContribution = txtContributionFunding.ToString
    '        .GrantApplicationCycleFundingStatusID = cmbStatus.ToString
    '        .GrantApplicationCycleFundingNotes = memFundingNotes.Text
    '    End With
    '    dc1.GrantApplicationCycleFundings.InsertOnSubmit(NewGrantApplicationCycleFundings)
    '    dc1.SubmitChanges()
    '        End If

    'dc1.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: What errors are you getting. How have you defined dc1? Have you imported System.Linq?

Comment: You mention ASP.Net, but your code looks like WinForms; is this a web app or a native app?

Comment: Looks like web app to me... but it could be either... its a button click with validation of objects and then an insert to sql.

Comment: Hey Mych I am not getting any error messages when I compile it just doesn't add the data? I am not sure if I have defined my dataclass1. I have built the data class on my solution and I have accessed the update stored procedure as GrantApplicationCycleFunding. I have not imported System linq. I will try that now!

Comment: Hey Justin I was given the asp.net book as I was tols it would assist me in developing this application but I cant really find any VB code that will help. It will (hopefully) be an online application portal!

Comment: Hey Mych I added System.Linq but to no avail. I will keep plugging away just now to see if I missed something. That's to you and Justin for your advice. Sometimes with coding I feel like im banging my head against a wall but will keep trying. Cheers again!

Comment: Try Dim btnSource = (From o In dc1.Update_GrantApplicationCycleFunding Where o.GrantApplicationID = Session("CurrentProjectID").ToString).First and not FirstOrDefault.

Comment: Maybe if you uncommented all that code it would do something?

Comment: Thanks Mych ill try that on Monday I will let you know the outcome. I fell its gotta be something simple im missing. Thanks big dog when im running it its not commented out. Was just making sure that this code is where my problem was coming from. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I have now managed to make the button add data to the datagrid. The big thing I missed was the declarations of the fields values at the bottom of the code and of course the databind! Never forget the correct DATABIND. You can adapt and use this in your own code if you are having similar problems! If you need help or explanation and I can help you then I will. Just add comment. Thanks

```
    ** ErrDetails.Text = ""
    ErrDetails.Visible = False
    FocusSet = False
    errCount = 0
    ErrDetails.Text = ""

    If spnTotalEstimatedCost.Value <= 0 Then
        ErrDetails.Text = ErrDetails.Text + "Please enter the cost." + vbNewLine
        ErrDetails.Visible = True
        If FocusSet = False Then
            spnTotalEstimatedCost.Focus()
            FocusSet = True
        End If
        errCount = errCount + 1
    End If

    If txtSourceFunding.Text = "" Then
        ErrDetails.Text = ErrDetails.Text + "Please........?" + vbNewLine
        ErrDetails.Visible = True
        txtSourceFunding.Focus()
        FocusSet = True
        errCount = errCount + 1
    End If

    If spnContributionFunding.Value = 0 Then
        ErrDetails.Text = ErrDetails.Text + "Please......" + vbNewLine
        ErrDetails.Visible = True
        spnContributionFunding.Focus()
        FocusSet = True
        errCount = errCount + 1
    End If

    If FocusSet = True Then
        ErrDetails.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        ErrDetails.Height = 20 * errCount
        ErrDetails.Visible = True
        Return
    End If

    Dim NewGrantApplicationMatchFundings As New GrantApplicationMatchFunding
    With NewGrantApplicationMatchFundings
        .GrantApplicationID = Session("CurrentProjectID")
        .GrantApplicationMatchFundingName = txtSourceFunding.Text
        .GrantApplicationMatchFundingContribution = spnContributionFunding.Value
        .GrantApplicationMatchFundingStatus = cmbStatus.SelectedItem.Value
        .GrantApplicationMatchFundingNotes = memFundingNotes.Text
    End With
    dc1.GrantApplicationMatchFundings.InsertOnSubmit(NewGrantApplicationMatchFundings)
    dc1.SubmitChanges()
    'End If


    'dc1.SubmitChanges()

    txtSourceFunding.Text = ""
    spnContributionFunding.Value = ""
    cmbStatus.Value = ""
    memFundingNotes.Text = ""
    grdFunding.DataBind()

     Dim btnTotal = (From o In dc1.Select_GrantApplicationMatchFundingTotal(Session("CurrentProjectID").ToString)).FirstOrDefault
    If Not IsNothing(btnTotal) Then
        spnTotalMatchFunding.Text = btnTotal.TotalFunding
        txtGrantFunding.Text = (spnTotalMatchFunding.Value / spnTotalEstimatedCost.Value) * 100
    Else
        spnTotalMatchFunding.Text = 0
        txtGrantFunding.Text = 0
    End If

    Dim cafChange = (From o In dc1.GrantApplicationCostsAndFundings Where o.GrantApplicationID.ToString = Session("CurrentProjectID").ToString).FirstOrDefault
    If Not IsNothing(cafChange) Then
        cafChange.GrantApplicationID = Session("CurrentProjectID")
        cafChange.GrantApplicationProjectCostsYear1 = spnTotalEstimatedCost.Value
        cafChange.GrantApplicationMatchedFundingNotesYear1 = memNotesMatchFunding.Text
        cafChange.GrantApplicationProjectRequestedYear1 = txtGrantFunding.Value
        dc1.SubmitChanges()
    Else
        Dim NewGrantApplicationCostsAndFundings As New GrantApplicationCostsAndFunding
        With NewGrantApplicationCostsAndFundings
            .GrantApplicationID = Session("CurrentProjectID")
            .GrantApplicationProjectCostsYear1 = spnTotalEstimatedCost.Value
            .GrantApplicationMatchedFundingNotesYear1 = memNotesMatchFunding.Text
            .GrantApplicationProjectRequestedYear1 = txtGrantFunding.Value
        End With
        dc1.GrantApplicationCostsAndFundings.InsertOnSubmit(NewGrantApplicationCostsAndFundings)
        dc1.SubmitChanges()
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Thanks to Mych and Justin Ryan for the help. I appreciate you trying!